# Users of my app want to import from their own salesforce accounts each, so an appflow flow per each user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, cloud, amazon-appflow

I set up appflow via gui (as PoC) and connected to one salesforce account to read the data. All great.

But now every user wants to connect their account within my multi tenant app to their very own salesforce account. Is this the correct way to handle this:

create and configure instance of appflow flow including steps to connect newly created instance to user's salesforce account of choice (obtain a key, etc). Then Create personal user s3 buckets where data would be dumped, lambdas which will process it and other necessary to let the user data be imported via appsync into multitenant dynamoDB.

That would result in *lots* of appflow flows, buckets and lambdas. is there better way? And if no, what is best way to provision the flows

- via cloud formation sdk in nodejs
- cdk (is it possible to use it within amplify gen1?)
- via call from nodejs to lambda which will create the flows